# Cambiar el nombre de un servidor con version sqlexpress

Tags: sql-server

Me podrian ayudar con una duda, tengo una version sqlexpress en cual al momento de acceder me sale asi PCTRAB\SQLEXPRESS, existe la posibilidad de cambiar el nombre del servidor Y quitar
el \SQLEXPRESS y solo dejar el nombre PCTRAB?.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guia

Comment: Revisa este enlace https://www.seabrookewindows.com/nQopo9lM4/

Answer (score 2):

Lamentablemente la forma correcta de hacerlo es reinstalar SQL Server Express y en la página de instalación de SQL Server llamada "Instance Configuration" elegir la opción "Default instance". Luego puedes hacer mover las bases de datos desde la instancia Express hacia la instancias default usando detach/attach o backup/restore.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un "workaround" que puedes implementar si no deseas reinstalar de nuevo es asignar el puerto default (por omisión) TCP 1433 a la instancia SQL Express que por lo normal usan un puerto dinámico. [Aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16) en la documentación de Microsoft te muestra los pasos para asignar el puerto 1433 a la instancia SQL Express. Luego de asignar ese puerto a la instancia Express te podrás conectar a ella de las siguientes formas adicionales como si fuese una instancia default:

- (local)
- localhost
- . ( <-- con un punto)
- 127.0.0.1